# App Script Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a document from a template using data from a googlesheet. I'm getting error like undefined 'length' on my code line 6. How can I fix this?

```
function createDocument() {
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1u19od0kZjo2AoVNT6xADPbRZYNCPSYASJYhQrVWT6Hk', 'A1:U1');
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1u19od0kZjo2AoVNT6xADPbRZYNCPSYASJYhQrVWT6Hk', 'A2:U');
  var templatedoc = '1LufBNP3BUCU2az_pvwNiOUicsIp7c3H1jRvNgjUuJJQ';
  
  ***for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++){***
    
    var supplier = data.values[i][0];
    
    
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    
    
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('Coaching' );
    
    
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    
    
    
    body.replaceText('##ctrl no##', "ctrl")
        
    
    parseTactics(headers.values[0], data.values[i], body);
    
  }

}

function parseTactics(headers, data, body){ 
  
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    {data[i] != '' && 
      body.appendListItem(headers[i] + ' | ' + data[i] + ' net').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue having `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. You will encounter this error whenever you are trying to read an empty range using [Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). `data.values` will be set to null since empty trailing rows and columns are omitted. See [Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range)

### Workaround:

Check first if `data.values` is null before checking its content.

```
if(data.values != null){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++){
    var supplier = data.values[i][0];
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('Coaching' );
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    body.replaceText('##ctrl no##', "ctrl")   
    parseTactics(headers.values[0], data.values[i], body);   
  }
}
```